# Have a fragment re-load on post execute

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a fragment which calls an async task. When the async task is done I want the fragment to completely re-load.

Basically, my fragment loads a random review. The user then rates the review with a star bar at the bottom. When they click the star bar a async task runs submitting the rating to my database.Once submitted I want another review to load.

My async code looks like this:

```
public class AddNoteRate extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context c;

    public AddNoteRate(Context context)
    {
        c = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        Fragment Fragment_three;
        FragmentManager man= c.getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
        Fragment_three = new RateReviews();
        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_three);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();




    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

This line I can not run in the async task:

```
    FragmentManager man= c.getFragmentManager();
```

Comment: c is Activity if your context is from Activity  try `(Activity)context`

Comment: use Activity instead of Context

Comment: Do not "reload" a `Fragment`, just update the `View`'s data.

Answer (score 1):

`getFragmentManager()` is a method of `Activity`, not `Context`.

Since you're probably passing in an `Activity` as the `context` parameter anyway, you could hack this with:

```
FragmentManager man = ((Activity) c).getFragmentManager();
```

but long term, best practice would be to pass either the `Activity` or the `FragmentManager` directly as an argument to the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I get a require android.support.v4.apps.Fragment>manager error

Comment: You need an import statement "import android.support.v4.apps.FragmentManager;" and if that gives an error you probably need to add the v4 support library to your project.  How to do that is answered elsewhere on SO.

Comment: What if 'c'  is indeed an Activity and this Activity's 'onDestroy'  is executed before this AsyncTask's 'onPostExecute'? Then you'll have a possible memory leak or at least reference to an invalid Activity in the 'onPostExecute' .. Be very careful of a Class having any field referencing an object that has a different life cycle.